# Jquery Slider Tabs - Open tab On click of link or ID

Tags: jquery, tabs

Hi i'm using this [Jquery Slider Tabs](https://github.com/lopatin/sliderTabs), I'm trying to open tab contents by clicking div having `id bypasstab`

My Html structure is,

```
<div id="bypasstab">General Link/div>

<div id="mySliderTabs">
  <!-- Unordered list representing the tabs -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#canyon">The Grand Canyon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#taj">The Taj Mahal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bigben">Big Ben</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Afterwards, include the div panels representing the panels of our slider -->
  <div id="canyon">
    <h3>The Grand Canyon</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="taj">
    <h3>The Taj Mahal</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="bigben">
    <h3>Big Ben</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
var slider = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs({
  autoplay: true,
  mousewheel: false,
  position: "bottom"
});
```

Anybody know how to do it ?

Comment: No one have any idea to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

//try work for me

```
$(function(){
/* FOR TAB*/
$('#tabs li a').click(function(e){
    $('#tabs li, #content .current').removeClass('current').removeClass('fadeInLeft');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $(currentTab).addClass('current fadeInLeft');
    e.preventDefault();

});

/* JS FOR BYPASS TAB */
 $('#bypass').click(function(e){  
    $('#tabs li, #content .current').removeClass('current').removeClass('fadeInLeft');
    $('#tabs1').addClass('current');//***** Tab change 
    var currentTab = $('#tabs li a').attr('href');
    $(currentTab).addClass('current fadeInLeft');
    e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

// HTML

```
<div id="tabwrap">
<ul id="tabs">
   <li id="tabs1" class="current"><a href="#con1"></a></li>
       <li id="tabs2"><a href="#con2"></a></li>
   <li id="tabs3"><a href="#con3"></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
 <div id="con1" class="current">bha bha</div>
 <div id="con2">bha bha</div>
 <div id="con3">bha bha</div>
</div>
 <a id="bypass" href="#con1">bha</a>
</div>
```